# Porque no me hace correctamente la última iteración de foreach en php?

Tags: php, html

estoy intentando obtener la ruta de unas imagenes almacenadas en la base de datos y luego mostrarlas en un slider. Lo que pasa es que quiero que cuando este en el home muestre la última foto guardada en la base de datos como la principal en el slider y esto lo hago con una clase "active" en el tag del div. Si lo hago de forma manual:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-items">
    <div  class="item">
      <img class="ampliar" src="uploads/flor.jpg" />
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="ampliar" src="uploads/logo.png" />
    </div> 
</div>
 <!-- slider controls -->
 <div class="left-slide"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></div>
 <div class="right-slide"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></div>
 <!-- slider controls -->
</div>
```

En el que vemos que la imagen "logo" tiene la clase active, por lo que se muestra la primera foto en el slider.

En el php he construido esto:

```
$sql = 'SELECT urlPath,description FROM photos';
$preparada = $db->prepare($sql);
$preparada->execute();

if($preparada){
  echo "<div class='slider'>";
  echo "<div class='slider-items'>";
  foreach ($preparada as $fila) {
    if($fila === end($fila)){
        echo "<div class='item active'>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class='item'>";
    }
    echo "<img class='ampliar' ";
    echo 'src="';
    echo "./uploads/".$fila['urlPath'];
    echo '"';
    echo '/>';
    echo "</div>";
  }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='left-slide'><i class='fas fa-thumbs-up'></i></div>";
    echo "<div class='right-slide'><i class='fas fa-thumbs-down'></i></div>";
    echo "</div>";
```

Encontre que con la función end podias mirar si era la última iteración y de esta forma añadiria el active para la última imagen, pero en el slider no me muestra nada ni me hace nada, pero si quito el if y dejo solamente el

```
echo "<div class='item active'>";
```

Me muestra todas las imagenes una encima de otra como primeras y al deslizar me las vuelve a mostrar bien, es como si los divs con class='item' solamente no los hace y la función end no me funciona. Estoy bastante atascado y no veo cual podria ser el problema.

Es como si al hacer el foreach no encontrara la última imagen para añadirle la clase active y al no hacerlo el resto de imagenes no se ven al tener clase item solamente.

Comment: `$preparada` no es un arreglo, sino un recurso para acceder a resultados de la consulta ejecutada. Deberías leer dentro de un ciclo, por ejemplo, suponiendo que usas la librería _mysqli_: `while($fila = $preparada->fetch_assoc()) { ... }`. Te sugiero que no te compliques: lee la consulta ordenando por fecha (o ID descendiente) y activa la primera foto.

Answer (score 0):

He mirado el codigo y la función end(), y esta función espera que le pases el array completo. En tu codigo deberías cambiar end($fila) por end($preparada).

Pero a lo mejor sería una buena práctica coger un id de los elementos que traes de la base de datos para hacer la comparación.

En conclusión, la función end() está esperando que le pases el array, en tu caso el array que estas iterando.

Comment: Lo probé con hacer end($preparada) , pero me dice "Expected type 'array'. Found 'PDOStatement|true'"

Comment: Y si pruebas a forzarlo con end((array) $preparada)) ?

Comment: Me dice que "Only variables can be passed by reference"

Comment: Siempre puedes probar a convertir el resultado de la consulta en un array y luego recorrerlo.